# How to display the content returned by a function in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react JS.
I want to display the graph after I click on 'check statistics' button. I can see that my function is getting executed but how to display whatever the function is returning? As handleShowStatistics() is a function, I can't write the render() method.
Here is my code of 'Quiz.js'

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";
import QuestionBank from "./QuestionBank.js";
import { Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";

class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userAnswer: null,
      currentIndex: 0,
      options: [],
      data: [],
      quizEnd: false,
      score: 0,
      disabled: true
    };
  }

  loadQuiz = () => {
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        question: QuestionBank[currentIndex].question,
        options: QuestionBank[currentIndex].options,
        answer: QuestionBank[currentIndex].answer
      };
    });
  };

  nextQuestionHandler = () => {
    const { userAnswer, answer, score } = this.state;

    if (userAnswer === answer) {
      this.setState({
        score: score + 1
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1,
      userAnswer: null
    });
  };

  previosQuestionHandler = () => {
    // const{userAnswer}=this.state
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex - 1,
      userAnswer: null
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadQuiz();
  }

  checkAnswer = (answer) =>
    this.setState({
      userAnswer: answer,
      disabled: false
    });

  finishHandler = () => {
    const { userAnswer, answer, score } = this.state;
    if (userAnswer === answer) {
      this.setState({
        score: score + 1
      });
    }
    if (this.state.currentIndex === QuestionBank.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        quizEnd: true
      });
    }
  };

  attemptAnotherTry = () => {
    this.loadQuiz();
    this.setState({
      userAnswer: null,
      currentIndex: 0,
      options: [],
      quizEnd: false,
      score: 0,
      disabled: true
    });
  };

  handleShowStatistics = () => {
    console.log("fucntion start");
    const { data } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      data: [
        {
          labels: ["Correct Answers", "Incorrect Answers"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "statistical chart",
              data: [this.state.score, 6 - this.state.score],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(255,99,132,1)", "rgba(255,205,86,1)"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
    console.log("fucntion end");

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            width: "1000px",
            height: "1000px",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginLeft: "250px"
          }}
        >
          {/* <Pie data={data} options={options}/> */}
          <Pie data={data} />
          <Link to="/Test" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Attempt test again
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    if (this.state.currentIndex !== prevState.currentIndex) {
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          disabled: true,
          question: QuestionBank[currentIndex].question,
          options: QuestionBank[currentIndex].options,
          answer: QuestionBank[currentIndex].answer
        };
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { question, options, currentIndex, userAnswer, quizEnd } = this.state;
    if (quizEnd) {
      return (
        <div className="containerBox">
          <h1> Game Over. Final score is {this.state.score} points</h1>
          <p> The correct answers for the quiz are</p>
          <ul>
            {QuestionBank.map((item, index) => (
              <li className="options" key={index}>
                {item.answer}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          {currentIndex === QuestionBank.length - 1 && (
            <button
              className="attemptButton"
              onClick={this.attemptAnotherTry}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            >
              Retest?
            </button>
          )}

          {currentIndex === QuestionBank.length - 1 && (
            <button onClick={this.handleShowStatistics}>
              Check Statistics
            </button>
          )}
          {/* <globalThis.pieChart/> */}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="containerBox">
        <div className="title">Quiz </div>
        <h2>{question}</h2>
        <span>{`Question ${currentIndex + 1} of ${QuestionBank.length}`}</span>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <p
            key={option.id}
            className={`options ${userAnswer === option ? "selected" : null}`}
            onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(option)}
          >
            {option}
          </p>
        ))}

        {currentIndex < QuestionBank.length - 1 && (
          <button
            disabled={this.state.disabled}
            onClick={this.nextQuestionHandler}
          >
            Next Question
          </button>
        )}
        {currentIndex < QuestionBank.length - 1 && currentIndex > 0 && (
          <button
            onClick={this.previosQuestionHandler}
            className="previousQuestion"
          >
            Previous Question
          </button>
        )}
        {currentIndex === QuestionBank.length - 1 && (
          <button onClick={this.finishHandler} disabled={this.state.disabled}>
            Finish
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Quiz;
```

Please help me with the solution. I am really stuck here and trying hard to display the graph.

Answer (score 0):

In the render, you can check if you have data and display your statistics here

```
return (
<div className="containerBox">
   {this.state.data && <Statistics data={this.state.data}/>}
   ...
</div>
)
```

Assuming you define a component Statistics to show your data

Calling the setState function will automaically recall the render method

Comment: My existing handleShowStatistics() function is a method inside the Quiz class component. The  function handleShowStatistics() is returning the graph but there is no render method to display the graph as it's a function. So how to display my graph in Quiz class component's render method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flag state which set to true if the use click Check Statistics button. So it will appear only if checkStatistics id true.

sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-rgb-z5tkj?file=/src/App.js

something like that:

```
 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       data: [],
       checkStatistics: false
     };
   }

  handleShowStatistics = () => {
    console.log("fucntion start");
    const { checkStatistics } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      checkStatistics: !checkStatistics
    });
    console.log("fucntion end");
  };

  render() {
    const { checkStatistics } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="containerBox">
        <div className="title">Quiz</div>
        <h2>Question</h2>
        <button onClick={this.handleShowStatistics}>Check Statistics</button>
        {checkStatistics && (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100px",
              height: "100px",
              textAlign: "center",
              marginLeft: "25px"
            }}
          >
            Show this div if checkStatistics is true
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: My existing handleShowStatistics() function is a method inside the Quiz class component. The function handleShowStatistics() is returning the graph but there is no render method to display the graph as it's a function. So how to display my graph in Quiz class component's render method?

Comment: In my answer you can find the graph in the component render method. As it will appears if checkStatistics state is true

Comment: Writing this line- {checkStatistics && (<div  gave me an error 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'.  You actually shifted some code from return to render in your changes? What will you return then?